# Fetch data from treasury.gov via API

Tags: python, api

I want to write a function in Python which can get the US Treasury 10 year bond yield of the most recent available date from https://home.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/TextView?type=daily_treasury_yield_curve&field_tdr_date_value_month=202302

I looked though the API documentation but still got no clue. Can anyone help me with it?
https://fiscaldata.treasury.gov/api-documentation/#list-of-endpoints

Comment: On that page, they have XML and CSV options for downloading the data. Seems like you can just put the current month into the URL, do a `requests.get()`, and parse the CSV or XML file that comes back. Have you tried something along those lines?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a free code-writing or tutorial service. We can help with problems in your code, but we don't do your homework for you. See [ask].

Comment: Work through some basic lesson like this https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-test-and-play-with-web-apis-the-easy-way-with-postman/ Then try again and come back if you have a specific question regarding your bond yield implementation.